# TCL Error: wrong # args: should be "source ?-encoding name? fileName"

Tags: scripting, tcl, tcltk

I am new to tcl

I wrote a code as ...

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh


# get all co-ordinates of cell from arguments
# if suffiecient arguments are not there then print error and exit
# Calculate area of cell


lassign $argv a b c d e f g h
if {$argc != 8} {
puts "Error in argument count"
exit
} elseif {$b > $d} {
puts "Error: x1 is greater than x2 value"
exit
} elseif {$f > $h} {
puts "Error: y1 value is greater than y2"
exit
}

puts "Everything is correct proceed"

set area [expr ($d - $b) * ($h - $f)]
puts "Area of cell is $area"
```

when executing in mac terminal as...

source ./special_var.txt x1 20 x2 30 y1 30 y2 60

i am getting error as ...

wrong # args: should be "source ?-encoding name? fileName"

Answer (score 1):

You've written a file that's trying to be a program (it has a `#!` line and depends on the `argv` global variable). That's fine, but you should run it with `tclsh` (explicitly or implicitly); you can't do it simply with `source`, which is a more primitive operation.

Running it as a subprocess is pretty easy:

```
exec [info nameofexecutable] ./special_var.txt x1 20 x2 30 y1 30 y2 60
# Or:
#   exec /usr/bin/tclsh ./special_var.txt x1 20 x2 30 y1 30 y2 60
# You might be able to guess what [info nameofexecutable] does...
```

or, if you have marked the file as executable in the OS:

```
exec ./special_var.txt x1 20 x2 30 y1 30 y2 60
```

Running in the current process is *slightly* trickier. The `source` command is more like `#include` in C; it doesn't do much special processing of arguments by itself, and if you want that then you have to do that first. It's not a lot of code...

```
set argv [list x1 20 x2 30 y1 30 y2 60]
source ./special_var.txt
```

We've never added that to `source` (and aren't going to!) because we don't usually want to interfere with `argv` just because we pull code from another file.

Comment: The `source` command is really just read-the-contents-of-the-file and then `eval` them. It's very simple-minded!